# Next js on AWS amplify, how to set Environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

During development, everything works, the application has  .env.local file. After installing to amazon amplify, the application does not see variables, I added my keys and values in Environment variables, and I also tried to add them to the console, but then the application breaks

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
      - EMAIL=${EMAIL}
           - EMAIL_PASS=${EMAIL_PASS}
           - NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS=${NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html) for organising your `yml` file. As you can see, `env` is at the top, followed by `variables`.

```
version: 1
env:
  variables:
    key: value
backend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - *enter command*
    build:
      commands:
        - *enter command*
    postBuild:
        commands:
        - *enter command*
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - cd react-app
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    files:
        - location
        - location
    discard-paths: yes
    baseDirectory: location
  cache:
    paths:
        - path
        - path
test:
  phases:
    preTest:
      commands:
        - *enter command*
    test:
      commands:
        - *enter command*
    postTest:
      commands:
        - *enter command*
  artifacts:
    files:
        - location
        - location
    configFilePath: *location*
    baseDirectory: *location*
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setting up environment variables for multiple environments on AWS Amplify and Next.js**

for local variables, just place them on .env.local

for more environments, set them up on Amlify.

On AWS A mplify dashboard select your project and click on 'Environment variables':
[image]

Now add a variable. This variable will be set for all of your envs.
The variable name should start with 'NEXT_PUBLIC_'.

For this variable, add an exception by clicking on 'Manage variables' > 'Actions' > 'Add variable override'.

(On this example, NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV is set for all branches, and than being replaced for branch 'master')

[image]